# Side pin in the Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

[image: Pin at the side of Visual Studio Editor]

I am not sure how that "pin" (highlighted in the pic) came from. I don't have any extensions installed. Would be really interested to know how It came and what is its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a pinned [datatip](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/22/the-best-of-visual-studio-2010-pin-a-datatip-to-source.aspx) to me

[image: datatip]